# mostrar una lista con php y sql

Tags: php, html, sql

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es, hacer dos SELECT.

El primero me muestra las regiones de  de la TABLA sucursales lo cual lo hace bien pero, mi segundo SELECT quiero que me muestre las sucursales dependiendo del resultado del primer SELECT (que casi seria el select de regiones).

Lo intente hacer de la siguiente manera pero el segundo SELECT sale vació y se que es por que mi variable $opciones no es del todo llena:

```php
<div class="card">
    <?php
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM sucursales";
    $ejecutar = mysqli_query($con, $consulta) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    ?>
    <div class="card-header">
        <h3 class="card-title">Region:
            <select name="nombre_regiones" id="region">
                <?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $opciones['region'] ?>"><?php echo $opciones['region'] ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <?php
    $consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM sucursales WHERE region='$opciones'";
    $ejecutar1 = mysqli_query($con, $consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    ?>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Sucursal:
                    <select name="nombre_regiones" id="region">
                        <?php foreach ($ejecutar1 as $opciones1) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $opciones1['nombre_sucursal'] ?>"><?php echo
                                                                                        $opciones1['nombre_sucursal'] ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5 class="card-title" id="porcentaje">0%</h5>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" role="form" action="monitoreo_x_region.php">
                        <div class="row"><input type='button' value="Ventas" onclick="aumentara1()">
                            <p id="aumentar1">0</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row"><input type='button' value="Visitas" onclick="aumentara()">
                            <p id="aumentar">0</p>
                        </div>
                        <div><input type='button' value="Obtener porcentaje" onclick="getValueInput()"></div>
                        <button type="submit" id="botonop" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Agregar ventas</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema con la variable `$opciones` es que es una variable local dentro de tu ciclo `foreach`

```
<?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones) : ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $opciones['nombre_sucursal'] ?>">
        <?php echo $opciones['nombre_sucursal'] ?>
    </option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Una vez terminado el ciclo la variable "deja de existir" por eso esta consulta no te devuelve nada

```
<?php
    $consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM sucursales WHERE region='$opciones'";
    $ejecutar1 = mysqli_query($con, $consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
?>
```

Además de que tendrías un error con esa consulta ya que le estás pasando un `arreglo` en lugar de un `valor`.

Una solución que se me ocurre es anidar tus ciclos

```
<?php foreach ($ejecutar as $opciones) : ?>

    ...

    <?php
        $consulta2 = "SELECT * FROM sucursales WHERE region=$opciones['region']";
        $ejecutar1 = mysqli_query($con, $consulta2) or die(mysqli_error($con));
    ?>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Sucursal:
                    <select name="nombre_regiones" id="region">
                        <?php foreach ($ejecutar1 as $opciones1) : ?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $opciones1['nombre_sucursal'] ?>"><?php echo
                                                                                        $opciones1['nombre_sucursal'] ?></option>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h5 class="card-title" id="porcentaje">0%</h5>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" role="form" action="monitoreo_x_region.php">
                        <div class="row"><input type='button' value="Ventas" onclick="aumentara1()">
                            <p id="aumentar1">0</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row"><input type='button' value="Visitas" onclick="aumentara()">
                            <p id="aumentar">0</p>
                        </div>
                        <div><input type='button' value="Obtener porcentaje" onclick="getValueInput()"></div>
                        <button type="submit" id="botonop" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i> Agregar ventas</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Solo como nota la variable no deja de existir se queda con el último valor `foreach ([1,2,3,4] as $v){} echo $v;//4`